# echo content data from url source

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Hey guys I'm not too knowledgeable about this particular topic in PHP yet. Basically I wanted to get a certain content of the url source so for instance the code below will only echo that specific content from the source page. I wanted to do this for other websites and the script below has errors but that's just like a demo of what I want to accomplished.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.jokesclean.com/OneLiner/Random/');
                                $data = getBetween($data,'<p class="c"> <font size="+2">',"</font></p>");
                                echo $data;
?>
```

All the information of the script above is located [here](http://pastebin.com/StnuKCp1)

Comment: Wouldn't you just use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)....?

Comment: what's the source code of the getBetween function?

Comment: @Mike function getBetween($content,$start,$end){$r = explode($start, $content);if(isset($r[1])){$r = explode($end, $r[1]);return$r[0]; }return'';}

Comment: And what error message do you see on the scren?

Comment: @Mike Apparently it's an synthax error on line 6, but I wanted to know what is wrong with the script that it resulted with that? The link to the entire script is posted above for any further information.

Comment: Your script actually works, in this particular case, there are no errors.

Comment: @nevermind Can you show me a screenshot of what you result with that script?

Comment: I didn't tested whole script, just tested getBetween() function on link you've provided. For the rest: probably HTML source is changed somewhere, so it has to be updated in script, too. P.S. Result is...well... joke text....

Answer (score 1):

Use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do this.

Read the manual to do this from [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). 
Its pretty simple.

```
//include simple_html_dom.php file.
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.jokesclean.com/OneLiner/Random/');
foreach($html->find('p[class=c]') as $e)
echo $e;
```

Just tested on my local system and it worked perfectly generating a random joke everytime i refresh

here's what i got on last refresh of this code.
.[image: here's what i got on last refresh]

Comment: I tried the script and ran it only as a PHP file on 000webhost and I resulted with "Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() ..... on line 3"

Comment: you need to download get and install the SimpleHTMLDOM library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/ and read manual from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm . its pretty simple. happy to help.ask again if not understood. :)

Comment: to install just download extract and upload it to your projects folder. Learn more by touching the example files add your code to one of the example file at fist after just extracting it to projects folder.hope this helps. :)

Comment: Okay so I uploaded all the files made an index file and added the script you posted above. Apparently the page comes out blank any clue?

Comment: now have a look at the code. add the include statement that i added just now and save the file in the same folder where the simple_html_dom.php file is. This should do the trick. if not let me know :)

Comment: "000webhost", ah, so... - file_get_contents() function, used in simple_html_dom is disabled there... (and not just there!)... you can test on your local machine...

Comment: updated the answer. it works as we want. didn't it? let me know :)

Comment: if its the correct answer please remember to thank me by accepting it as the correct answer. That would be so helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to use domdocument but you can also do it using regular expressions like the following.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.jokesclean.com/OneLiner/Random/');
if ( preg_match('/\<font size="\+2"\>(.*?)\<\/font\>/', $data, $match) ) {
   echo $match['1'];
}
else {
   echo 'couldn\'t find a match';
}
```